# Convert Esri ASCII grid raster format to GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, esri-ascii-raster

I received data as *.asc file. How can I convert the ASCII data into a *.GeoJson file including polygons and the band data? I've tried various approaches with `rasterio` and `gdal` but they always returned one of the following errors which I was unable to solve:

`CRSError: The EPSG code is unknown. PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db`

`ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files`

The head of my *.asc data looks as follows:

```
ncols         720
nrows         360
xllcorner     -180.0000
yllcorner     -90.0000
cellsize      0.5000
NODATA_value  -9999
```

I figures, maybe I can simply draw my own grid of 720*360=259200 cells and assign the values in the `*.asc` file. However, the file readme suggests the data comprises 67420 cells which I do not really understand.

[image]

I can import the data into a np.array() via

```
import rasterio

src = rasterio.open('data.asc')

data = src.read(1)
```

The next step would be to create a GeoDataFrame and link the data array.

Comment: No, it describes a squared grid with ncols/nrows.

Comment: The asc file is a simple interchange text file for RASTER data. It does not contain POLYGON information, just the value at the pixel location. [GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) is for VECTOR data. So what you are asking makes no sense.

Comment: Asc files contain a georeference (via the length and width of each cell) so do geojson files. Hence there should be a way to store the same information in a geojson file.

Comment: @Hornbydd put it better what I as trying to say in my comment. It wasn't a question.

Comment: for a GDAL solution try https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html

Comment: Somehow, I cannot GDAL to run. It always returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with my own solution.

First of all, I import some packages:

```
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
```

Then, I import the *.asc file and check what bands it contains. I save the band in a DF and create a plot.

```
src = rasterio.open('data.asc')
print("Bands: " + str(src.indexes))
data = src.read(1)

plt.imshow(data)
```

[image]

The *.asc file has 360 rows and 720 columns. This means I have a raster with grid cells of the size 180/360 * 360/720 = 0.5 * 0.5 arcminutes. I create the corresponding grid via:

```
stepsize = 0.5 # Degree

lonmin = -180 # X #
lonmax = 180 # X # 

latmin = -90 # Y 
latmax = 90 # Y

cells = int((latmax*2*1/stepsize)*(lonmax*2*1/stepsize))

i = 0
stepsize = int(stepsize*2) # Avoid float numbers in for loops
grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=range(cells), columns = ['count','geometry'])


for y in range(latmin*2, latmax*2, stepsize): # For all rows Y
    for x in range(lonmin*2, lonmax*2, stepsize): # For all columns X

        # Create square/grid cell
        a = (stepsize/2+(x**stepsize/2),y*(-1)*stepsize/2) # Start at 
        b = (stepsize/2+(x**stepsize/2),y*(-1)*stepsize/2-stepsize/2)
        c = (stepsize/2+(x**stepsize/2-stepsize/2),y*(-1)*stepsize/2-stepsize/2)
        d = (stepsize/2+(x**stepsize/2-stepsize/2),y*(-1)*stepsize/2)

        cell = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([a,b,c,d])])

        grid['geometry'][i] = cell[0]
        grid['count'][i] = i
        i = i + 1
```

Since my grid is saved in a one-dimensional GeoDataFrame, I also turn the ASCII data into GeoDataFrame of the same dimension:

```
ascii_onedim = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['band_1'])

for x in range(360): # For all rows
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data[x:x+1])
    for y in range(720): #For all columns
        ascii_onedim = ascii_onedim.append({'band_1': temp.iloc[0,y]}, ignore_index=True)
del temp
```

I also introduce a "count" column, so that I have a key for concatenating both dataframes.

```
ascii_onedim = ascii_onedim.reset_index()
ascii_onedim.columns=['count','band1']
```

Concatenating

```
final = pd.concat([ascii_onedim, grid], axis=1)
```

Somehow, the geometries are not recognized as such. I fix this via:

```
final = final.set_geometry('geometry')
```

Then, I plot:

```
final.plot(column='band1')
```

[image]

I successfully turned the data from the *.ascii file into a GeoDataFrame which I can save via `grid.to_file('filename.json', driver='GeoJSON')`.
I am not great with Python so please forgive me the style of code. I am sure, there are nicer way to achieve the same results.